# Convert array to array of objects with key as same as value

Tags: javascript

how do I convert an array to array of objects with the key being the same as value?

```js
var abc = ["abc", "def"];

var sed = abc.map(function(a, index) {
 return {
   a: a,
    key: a
  }
})

console.log(sed);
```

My output should look like

```
[{
  abc: "abc",
  key: "abc"
 },
 {
 def: "def",
 key: "def"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put brackets around the `[a]` to turn it into a computed property.

```js
var abc = ["abc", "def"];

var sed = abc.map(function(a, index) {
  return {
    [a]: a,
    key: a
  }
})

console.log(sed);
```

Comment: You can omit the `index` argument there. Also, this makes a nice one-liner: `abc.map(a => ({ [a]: a, key: a }))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```js
var abc = ["abc", "def"];

var sed = abc.map(function(a, index) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[a] = a;
    obj['key'] = a;
 return obj;
})

console.log(sed);
```